# On pushing object to array all values of one specific varaible in the object becomes the same

Tags: javascript

I'm create pushing the same object 10 times to an array, but every time it pushes it changes a variable inside the object with +1. But when the loop finishes, all the variables inside all the objects end up with 10 ( the same value ). Why is this?

Example:

```
var obj = {}
var array = [];

for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    obj.number = i;
    array.push(obj);
}
```

When I then 
    console.log(array)

It returns the array but all the obj's have the same number. Why is this?

Comment: you are updating the same object whole the time

Comment: move object initialization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are pushing an object in your array, meaning you are pushing a **reference** to the same object; if you are changing your object somewhere, it will be changed everywhere.

You can either :

Create a new object at each iteration :

```js
var array = [];

for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    var obj = {}
    obj.number = i;
    array.push(obj);
}

console.log(array);
```

Or, clone the object to make sure the changes won't be applied to the reference

```js
var obj = {}
var array = [];

for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    let newObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))
    newObject.number = i;
    array.push(newObject);
}

console.log(array);
```